# Firebase List Objects to Observable Array in Angular 2

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I've integrated [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) with my Angular 2 project. Flashlight does the following:

1. Automatically indexes specified Firebase paths to an ElasticSearch cluster and monitors those paths for changes, re-indexing any changes.
2. Responds to query objects written to a specified Firebase path (e.g., 'search/request'), writing ElasticSearch responses to a specified Firebase path (e.g., 'search/response').

Responses are written to Firebase with the following structure:

[image]

Using Angularfire 2, this is what my search looks like:

```
searchThreads(term: string) {
    let queryBody: Object = {
        index: 'firebase',
        type: 'thread',
        q: term
    }
    this.requestKey = this.af.database.list('/search/request').push(queryBody).key
}
```

if I want the raw results of that search with all paths shown in the image above, I'd do something like this:

```
this.af.database.list(`search/response/${this.requestKey}`)
```

What I want is the objects found at `_source`. I want to iterate over the response `hits` and populate my view with those objects. How can I get just these objects into an observable array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to extract only the `_source` children. However, you could make it more efficient than extracting the complete search response.

Each hit contains little information additional to the source, so just retrieve the hits and map each hit to its `_source`.

```ts
this.af.database
  .list(`search/response/${this.requestKey}/hits/hits`)
  .map(hits => hits.map(hit => hit._source))
```

Also, you could use a limit query to extract a subset of `hits`:

```ts
this.af.database
  .list(`search/response/${this.requestKey}/hits/hits`, {
    query: {
      limitToFirst: 10
    }
  })
  .map(hits => hits.map(hit => hit._source))
```

Or, if you have some criteria for a minimum score, you could perform a query after ordering by child:

```ts
this.af.database
  .list(`search/response/${this.requestKey}/hits/hits`, {
    query: {
      orderByChild: '_score',
      startAt: 1.0
    }
  })
  .map(hits => hits.map(hit => hit._source))
```

(I've not used Flashlight, so I'm not sure how the scoring works, but some combination of `startAt` and/or `endAt` should let you refine your query.)

Comment: Thanks @cartant. I think you've answered almost all of my questions in the past week! Storing this in an observable array is as easy as `this.threads = this.af.database
  .list(`search/response/${this.requestKey}/hits/hits`)
  .map(hits => hits.map(hit => hit._source))` if I put that in the constructor or within `ngOnInit()`. But I can't get the observable to emit anything new if If I put the code inside of a method that takes the term as an observable and assigns the query to `this.threads`

Comment: Why that might be happening depends on a lot of context. If you cannot get it working, perhaps ask another question - including your component, etc. In the interim, you could inject a [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html) into the component's constructor - `constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef)` - and could call `this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` after you set `this.threads` to force change detection.